# Can I change the number of service proviers listed?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there a configuration setting anywhere that I can change the number of items listed on the Service Providers page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The value defined under the tag `<ItemsPerPage>15</ItemsPerPage>` (default value is 15) in `<Product-Home>/repository/conf/carbon.xml` file is used as the number of items to be displayed on a management console page. This is used at the backend server for the pagination of various items. In order to change the number of service providers to be listed on one page, you have to change this value, but that change affects all other listings in the management console (eg: user list, identity providers list).

If you use IS-5.10.0, this configuration can't be done via the `deployment.toml` file because that property is not templated. Instead, you can change the value in between `<ItemsPerPage></ItemsPerPage>` tags in `<Product-Home>/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/carbon.xml.j2` and restart the server. Then the property in `carbon.xml` will be changed.

Comment: Thank you!  That's what I was looking for!